# squashing 4 commits - `rebase master -i` or `rebase -i`

Tags: git, github, version-control

if I want to squash 4 commits into one united commit.

which command should I use?

I tried to understand the difference between them, please correct me if I'm mistaken.

```
git rebase -i HEAD~4
```

this just opens an editor with all the last local commits that weren't pushed?

So I can squash them before pushing?

vs

```
git rebase master -i
```

which actually does rebase from master into local branch,

here i will see master commits that were pushed already and it's not a good idea to squash them. This should be avoided, no? as it's a bad practice to change pushed commits

Comment: After 900 questions I would expect you to understand how this site works and how to ask a specific question.

Comment: sorry posted too early i edited my question

Comment: I count four question marks in your post. Have you tried to solve some of them yourself? What was the output? Why didn't it answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

When rebasing master (or any other branch) you are importing the given branch's commits to your current branch. When only `rebase -i` you are editing only your current branch history.
The editor then asks you what you want to do with your branch's history, because there you can delete commits, squash commits, or even reorder them.
In your particular case, you'll need to:

```
$ git rebase -i HEAD~5
```

You want to rebase from `HEAD~5` because git needs a base commit to squash from and since you want to squash 4, then 5 is your number.

In the editor screen you just look for the commits to squash and change their state from `pick` to `squash`.
That's it.